# Intalling Wordpress on a VPS using ssh

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ssh, installation

I was hoping to install Wordpress onto my vps server. I FTP'd the WP files into my web root. I had created the database, initialDB and the user, new_user using ssh. I believe the issue to be that the database perhaps was saved elsewhere than localhost or perhaps a permission issue. Note the following table:

```
SELECT user,
-> host
-> FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user | host |
+------------------+-----------+
| new_user | % |
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| root | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ultimately I am seeking assistance making sure everything is configured correctly. Please see the attached [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Ah.png) for the installation process for WP and the error I am receiving.
[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Resolved-  Thanks everyone.  I just ended up creating a new user so either I had the previous password wrong or because wordpress was looking for specifically "localhost" for the database rather than "%" that was used.

Comment: Please accept this as the answer so this question doesn't come up as unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the user does not have privileges to to actions on the db (Like delete, insert etc). Give the user all privileges and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the user? Most likely, you have created it but not given it access to the DB.

You have probably already run this command:

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_user_password';
```

And you most likely now need to run this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON initialDB.* TO 'new_user'@'%';
```

For further information on creating users and giving access to databases, you can read about the [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you renamed the [wp-config-sample.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-config-sample.php) to wp-config.php and replaced the following values? :

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```